# Only add random number to list in loop when doesn't already exist

Tags: c#, list, loops, random

New to using lists.  For automated testing purposes I am generating a list of distinct values.  The following is a code block of concern:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> lVars = new List<int>();

        while (VarsCount < randVarsCount)
        {
            if(VarsCount > 0)
            {
                while(lVars.Distinct().Count() != lVars.Count()) 
                {
                    lRowVars.Insert(VarsCount, rnd.Next(1, 11)); //problem code 
                }
            }
            lVars.Add(rnd.Next(1, 11));
            MessageBox.Show(lRowVars[aRowVarsCounter].ToString());
            aRowVarsCounter++;
        }
```

Basically, how do I check to see if the int being added matches all of the list (as my code doesn't work)....I've tried some other code but ends up being ALOT of extra code and loops; usually when I feel I'm doing something superfluous I find there is an easier way.

Comment: If the set of values if known and fixed ; create an array (or other) and shuffle it ; if not use an HashSet (or similar) to ensure it only contains each item only once (and it's Add method returns if it was already there or not)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the problem of "problem code"? Also you will probably run into trouble, if you want to add more than 10 values.

Comment: Your inner while loop is wrong.  You add the duplicate then test if there is a duplicate and stop.  You need to test if the value exists before you insert the new item

Comment: @jdweng I know...that is precisely what I want...trying to see if item exists withouth have to do a bunch of other loops...is this possible?

Comment: Normal method is to make a two dimensional list 2 x 11.  Column 1 add numbers 1 to 11.  Column 2 add random numbers.  Then sort by random numbers.  This way you don't get duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When thinking "list with distinct values", think "set" instead if you don't care about ordering (as appears to be the case here).  A set only contains a given value at most once.  You can do something like

```
int maxRnd = 11;
int desiredCount = 4;
if (desiredCount > maxRnd) throw new Exception("Impossible.");

HashSet<int> unique = new HashSet<int>();
while (unique.Count < desiredCount)
{
    unique.Add(rnd.Next(1, maxRnd));
}

// If needed, convert to a list

var uniqueList = unique.ToList();
```

Comment: watch out if desiredCount is larger than 10 :-)

Comment: @JeffOrris: How does order matter if the numbers are generated randomly to begin with?  There is no inherent order to random numbers.

Comment: @JeffRSon: Yeah thought about that while writing :-)  Added an explicit check.

Comment: @EricJ. my fault...misinterpreted what you were saying....the actual order of the list matters in my result but doesn't matter on the check; thanks for your time.